# PowerShell Issue with overwriting existing XLSX files

Tags: excel, powershell

Looking for some PowerShell assistance with a script we have. It was setup to take CSV files and save them as XLSX. It works fine except for when something happens and some XLSX files get left in the folder. The next time it runs a pop up comes up saying the file already exists and asking if we want to overwrite. This becomes a problem when running this unattended since there is nobody there to answer those prompts.

I searched online and already tried various suggestions non of which have helped. Tried the following:

- $excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
- $workbook.SaveAs ($path, $xlFixedFormat,
  AccessMode:=xlExclusive,ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges)

Looking for some help to stop these overwrite prompts. Any solution would work - either overwrite the file without prompt or even delete existing file before saving it again...

Here is the existing script:

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$folderpath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$filetype

 

 )
write-host "PowerShell to convert the files to xlsx format started"
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
$xlFixedFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlOpenXMLWorkbook
write-host $xlFixedFormat
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$excel.visible = $false
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$datetime = get-date -Format "yyyyMMdd"
$backuppath = $folderpath + "Xlsx_Old"

 

$folderpath = $folderpath +"*"

 

 

#Creating Xlsx_Old Folder
write-output "XLSX Old Files Folder"

 

write-host $backuppath
if(-not (test-path $backuppath))
{
    new-item $backuppath -type directory
}

 

write-output $backuppath

 

write-output "Here"

 

 

write-output $folderpath
write-output $filetype

 

Get-ChildItem -Path $folderpath -Include $filetype -Recurse 1 | 
ForEach-Object `
{

 


    write-output $path

 

    $path = ($_.fullname).substring(0, ($_.FullName).lastindexOf("."))
    
    write-output "Converting $path"
    $workbook = $excel.workbooks.open($_.fullname)

 

    $path += ".xlsx"
    Remove-Item -Path $path -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

 

    write-output $path

 

    if (test-path $path) 
    {
        $NewName = split-path $path -Leaf
        $NewName = $path.Substring(0,$path.LastIndexOf("."))
        write-host $NewName
        write-host $backuppath
        $NewName = $NewName+$datetime+".xlsx"
        write-host $NewName
        if(test-path $NewName)
        {
        rename-item $path $NewName
        move-item $NewName $backuppath -Force
        }
    }
    
        $excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
        #$workbook.saveas($path, $xlFixedFormat)
        $workbook.SaveAs ($path, $xlFixedFormat, AccessMode:=xlExclusive,ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges)
        $workbook.close()
    
    $oldFolder = $path.substring(0, $path.lastIndexOf("\")) + "\SourceFiles"
    
    write-host $oldFolder
    if(-not (test-path $oldFolder))
    {
        new-item $oldFolder -type directory
    }
    
    move-item $_.fullname $oldFolder -Force
    
}
$excel.Quit()
$excel = $null
[gc]::collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making this a bit harder than need be.

Try this rewrite of your code:

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)] [string]$folderpath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 1)][string]$filetype = '*.csv'
)

$folderpath = 'D:\Test'
$filetype = '*.csv'

Write-Host "PowerShell to convert the $filetype files to xlsx format in $folderpath"

# create the backup path folder if this does not already exist
$backuppath = Join-Path -Path $folderpath -ChildPath "Xlsx_Old"
$null = New-Item -Path $backuppath -ItemType Directory -Force

# create the SourceFiles folder if this does not yet exist
$sourcepath = Join-Path -Path $folderpath -ChildPath 'SourceFiles'
$null = New-Item -Path $sourcepath -ItemType Directory -Force

Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
$xlFixedFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlOpenXMLWorkbook  # 51

$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$excel.Visible = $false
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

# add brackets around the Get-ChildItem part, so it completes before sending the objects through the pipeline
(Get-ChildItem -Path $folderpath -Filter $filetype -File) | 
ForEach-Object {
    $outFile = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_.FullName, '.xlsx')
    # if the output file already exists, move it to the backup folder with the date included in the filename
    if (Test-Path -Path $outFile -PathType Leaf) {
        $NewName = Join-Path -Path $backuppath -ChildPath ('{0}_{1:yyyyMMdd}.xlsx' -f $_.BaseName, (Get-Date))
        Move-Item -Path $outFile -Destination $NewName -Force
    }
    $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($_.FullName)
    $workbook.SaveAs($outFile, $xlFixedFormat)
    $workbook.Close()
    # next move the source CSV file to the $sourcepath folder
    $_ | Move-Item -Destination $sourcepath -Force
}

# exit Excel and clean up the COM objects from memory
$excel.Quit()
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it and it works but I end up with XLSX and CSV files in the SourceFiles folder afterwards. Original script only moves the converted CSV files from parent folder to SourceFiles after processing. Looks like the rewrite moves all files from parent to SourceFiles

Comment: @JetRocket11 Ah, that's because of `-Recurse -Depth 1`. I'll remove it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is a great pragmatic solution but for the record you can do it the way the OP requested - snippet:

```
# Overwrite mode
$saveConflictResolution = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution]::xlLocalSessionChanges
$workbook.SaveAs($path, $xlFixedFormat, $saveConflictResolution)
```